# reminders in ionic app without server code

Tags: ionic-framework, reminders

Was anyone implemented a reminder system in an ionic app without server side code?

Basically, I'm building an ionic app (targeting Android and IOS) and I want to setup reminders. But my main problem is figuring out how to trigger them when the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check that plugin out : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

This let you not put the app from sleep when exiting app.

However, this will not replace a push notification feature.